# Managing Python Versions

Tags: python, macos, command, version, homebrew

So, for some reason, I have way too many versions of python on my Mac.

Running `python` in the terminal gets me Python 2.7.10.

`python2` gets me Python 2.7.14.

`python2.7` gets me  2.7.13.

`python2.6` gets me 2.6.9.

`python3` gets me 3.6.3.

`python3.6` gets me 3.6.3 again. Not sure if this is a separate install or not.

`python3.4` gets me 3.4.7.

So I have 6, possibly 7 versions of Python. And I have no idea what to do.

As for pip, I have the following installed: `pip`, `pip2`, `pip2.6`, `pip2.7`, `pip3`, and `pip3.6`.

Some of these versions of Python were shipped with the OS, and others were installed with Homebrew.

So it's a terrifying, yet sort of hilarious mess I've gotten myself into. How can I better manage my versions? Most of the versions installed I do not use, but can't remove them because they are part of the system. So how can I make my Python versions less of a pain?

Answer (score 3):

I recommend looking into [pyenv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv), it makes managing multiple versions of Python much easier. With the [virtualenv plugin](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv-virtualenv) life gets even better. With both installed you can do something like this:

```
pyenv install 2.7.13
pyenv install 3.5.1
pyenv install 3.6.3

pyenv virtualenv 2.7.13 proj1
pyenv virutalenv 3.6.3  proj2

pyenv activate proj2
python -V   # 3.6.3

pyenv activate proj1
python -V   # 2.7.13
```

And of course each project now has its own clean virtual environment you can install packages in with `pip`.